# Comparing and analyzing two rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

How to compare and analyze the two rasters in QGIS?

I have two raster images.

1. reference image
2. Georeferenced image based on ref image.

I want to check the accuracy, such as how much the image moved and rotated by overlapping the GCP image with the reference image.

Please tell me the function to check the accuracy of the two rasters or how to calculate using R or Python scripts.

I used the Python script. The error was calculated using Left Upper X,Y of image and ref. (Please let me know if this is not how you calculate the error.)

```py
from qgis.core.import QgsProject
from osgeo import gdal
from math import sqrt

gdal.AllRegister()
image_open = gdal.Open('C:/Users/Desktop/qgis/image.tif',1)
ref_open = gdal.Open('C:/Users/Desktop/qgis/ref.tif',1)

im_gt = image_open.GetGeoTransform()
ref_gt = ref_open.GetGeoTransform()

im_list = list(im_gt)
ref_list = list(ref_gt)

deltaX = ref_list[0] - im_list[0]
deltaY = ref_list[3] - im_list[3]
rmse = sqrt(pow(deltaX,2)+pow(deltaY,2))

print(rmse)
```

I can calculate the amount of movement of x,y, but if the image has been rotated, I wonder how much it has been rotated in x,y coordinates.